# How do I calculate the PDF of a bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: c++, opencv, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have a set of points and extract a small subset of them for calculating a bivariate normal distribution. Afterwards I check all other points if they fit in this distribution by calculating the PDF for every point and rejecting points with a value below some threshold.

So much about the theory...

The PDF has according to wikipedia the formula:

[image: formula]

σ is the standard deviation and μ is the mean, calculated as following:

```
cv::Scalar mean;
cv::Scalar stdDev;
dataPoints = dataPoints.reshape(3); // convert 3 columns to 3 channels
cv::meanStdDev(dataPoints, mean, stdDev);
dataPoints = dataPoints.reshape(1); // convert back
meanX = mean.val[0];
meanY = mean.val[1];
sigmaX = stdDev.val[0];
sigmaY = stdDev.val[1];
```

dataPoints is a cv::Mat with 3 columns of floats (x, y, index).

ρ is the correlation coefficient which I calculate like this:

```
cv::matchTemplate(dataPoints.col(0), dataPoints.col(1), rho, cv::TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

The last step is calculating the the probability for each point using this:

```
double p = (1. / (2. * M_PI * sigmaX * sigmaY * sqrt(1. - pow(rho, 2))));
double e = exp((-1. / 2.) * D(x, y, rho));
double ret = p * e;
```

And D() should be as far as I know the Mahalanobis Distance, but the formula from OpenCV `cv::Mahalanobis(x, y, rho)` returns another value than when I calculate it myself:

```
double cX = (x - meanX) / sigmaX;
double cY = (y - meanY) / sigmaY;
double a = (1. / (1. - pow(rho, 2)));
double b = (pow(cX, 2) + pow(cY, 2) - 2. * rho * cX * cY);
double ret = a * b;
```

So and now my Problem:

As far as I know the integral over the PDF should be 1 and the maximum value of the PDF should be at `(meanX, meanY)`, so when σ would be 0 the PDF at mean should be 1. But with the computations above I can get values over 1. What do I get wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't mean the PDFs the stackoverflow tag [pdf] is all about...

Comment: yes, sorry. I mean probability density function

Comment: `double e = exp((-1. / 2.) * D(x, y, rho))` doesn't quite match that formula - what happened to the `(1 - rho^2)` bit?

Comment: Why not use matrix notation?

Comment: it is in the D() -> double a = (1. / (1. - pow(rho, 2)));

Comment: why should I use matrix notation, it would make it more complicate, or not?